# How do I use swagger-ui?

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, swashbuckle

I'm using the Swashbuckle NuGet package in my web api project and I was trying to replace the default Swagger UI with this one 
https://github.com/jensoleg/swagger-ui

but I keep getting this error message

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<Error>
<Message>An error has occurred.</Message>
<ExceptionMessage>Embedded resource not found - ReportsAPI.swagger-ui.Index.html</ExceptionMessage>
<ExceptionType>Swashbuckle.SwaggerUi.AssetNotFound</ExceptionType>
<StackTrace> at Swashbuckle.SwaggerUi.EmbeddedAssetProvider.GetEmbeddedResourceStreamFor(EmbeddedAssetDescriptor resourceDescriptor, String rootUrl) at Swashbuckle.SwaggerUi.EmbeddedAssetProvider.GetAsset(String rootUrl, String path) at Swashbuckle.Application.SwaggerUiHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)</StackTrace>
</Error>
```

I followed the advice from this post
[Replace Swashbuckle UI completely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31647635/replace-swashbuckle-ui-completely)

But was unable to get it to work

I have a basic ASP.Net Web API 2 (simple rest api with no website or index html)

So I downloaded the zip file from the GitHub page of swagger-ui and copied the  dist folder to my project and included it as (tried both Content and Embedded resource) - and renamed dist folder to swagger-ui

So my root project folder now looks like

[image]

Then I changed my Swagger config to add the following

```
c.CustomAsset("index", thisAssembly, "ReportsAPI.swagger-ui.Index.html");
```

Is that correct? I'm not sure where to go from here

Do I have to include all other files as Embedded resource? Or just the Index.html?  What do I mark the other files as, Content? Copy always?

Comment: Can you provide some details on how you replaced the default Swagger UI with that one? Do you have that project on GitHub?

Comment: @HelderSepulveda I don't have the project on github.  I basically thought all you had to do was copy the 'dist' folder from the swagger-ui into my web api project root folder, then point the swagger config to the new index.html.  Is there something else I have to do?

Comment: To do it right you need to change swashbuckle to use that version of the swagger-ui... I guess your idea could work too, but will require a lot of trial and error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an alternative that does not require you to embed anything into your project:

https://raw.githack.com/jensoleg/swagger-ui/master/dist/index.html?url=https://swagger-net-test.azurewebsites.net/swagger/docs/V1

As you can see my swagger spec is provided with in the url parameter.
You could use that `raw.githack.com` or just copy the dist folder to a more convenient location.

---

Now I would like to point out that is a very old version of swagger-ui and does not look to be well maintained, maybe you should take a look at: **ReDoc** https://github.com/Rebilly/ReDoc/blob/master/README.md